# php Post txt file content to textarea on another page

Tags: php

I am writing an app to delete and modify files in a directory. I deleted files successfully. And now I want to modify and update content to the same file using textarea on another page.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <div class="span7">
  <table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th> List of files </th>
    <tr>
   </thead>
    <?php
    $files = glob("UploadFile/"."*");
    foreach($files as $txt)
    {
     if(mime_content_type($txt)=="text/plain")
     {
      $txtname = basename($txt);
      echo "<tr><td><input type='radio' name='txt' value='$txtname'/>&emsp;".$txtname."</td></tr>";
     }
    }
    ?>
  </table>
  </div>
  <div class="span8">
   <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit">Edit</button>
   <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete">Delete</button>
  </div>
  <?php
  global $txtname;
  $val = $_POST["submit"];
  $txtname = $_POST["txt"];
   if($val=="Delete")
      unlink("UploadFile/".$txtname);
       else if($val=="Edit")
   {
    $content=file_get_contents("UploadFile/".$txtname);
    header('Location:/edit.php');
           /* send content to this 'edit.php' page */
     }
  ?>
  </form>
```

And the edit.php page, i simply checked if the code is working. It works fine.

```
 <?php
 if($_POST['append'])
{
 $file_open = fopen("UploadFile/file.txt","a+");
 fwrite($file_open, $_POST['append']);
 fclose($file_open);
}
?>  
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="post">
  <textarea name="append" value="">
    <?php
    echo $content;
    $datalines = file ("UploadFile/file.txt");
    foreach ($datalines as $zz)
    {
     echo $zz;
    }
    ?>
 </textarea>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" value="save"> Save </button>
```

How do I get the contents of the file to textarea for modifying it.
Update: I want to save changes to the same file. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['text']))
{
    file_put_contents("file.txt",$_POST['text']);
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit;
}
$text = file_get_contents("file.txt");
?>  
<form method="post">
<textarea name="text"><?=$text?></textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

with listing

```
if(isset($_POST['text']))
{
    file_put_contents("UploadFile/".basename($_POST['file']),$_POST['text']);
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit;
}
if(isset($_GET['file']))
{
    $text = file_get_contents("UploadFile/".basename($_GET['file']));
?>  
    <form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="file" value="<?=urlencode($_GET['file'])?>">
    <textarea name="text"><?=$text?></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
<?
} else {

    $files = glob("UploadFile/*");
    foreach ($files as $f)
    {
        $f=basename($f);
?><a href="?file=<?=urlencode($f)?>"><?=htmlspecialchars($f)?></a><br><?
    }
}
```

Comment: I created a file with above code and directed my file. The text area seems to be empty, am i doing the wrong process? Explain details of code please